# Matching values from explode and while loop for checkbox

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to match any variables from database into another while loop  and if theres a match, check a checked box...

ForEG: Member places services they offer in database: cleaning,gardening,decorating,etc

I get this and explode...

Then I'm getting the list of categories from the categories table and if there's a match, Check the box.

I've tried doing them both as an array and trying to match the arrays but it seems all check boxes are ticked and I'm sure they'll be a more refined way of doing this so i ask for help with this please as I'm stuck in getting only the ones selected checked.

```
$servicesar = explode(",", $services);
foreach($servicesar as $serres) {
    $servicessplit .= ''.$serres.'';
}

$servcatselects = '';
$servcatresult = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM `servcats`");
while($scrow = mysqli_fetch_array($servcatresult)){
    $cattitle = $scrow["title"];

    if($servicessplit == $cattitle){
        $scchecked = 'checked="checked"';
    }

    $servcatselects .= '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$cattitle.'" value="'.$cattitle.'" '.$scchecked.'>'.$cattitle.'</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

Comment: The first loop can be replaced with `$servicessplit = str_replace(',', '', $services);`. But I don't understand why you're concatenating all the services without `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concatenate all the services into a single string. Keep them in an array, and use `in_array()` to test if the service from the table matches one of them.

Also, you need to set `$scchecked` to an empty string when there's no match. Otherwise, it keeps the value from the previous category.

```
$servicesar = explode(",", $services);

$servcatselects = '';
$servcatresult = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM `servcats`");
while($scrow = mysqli_fetch_array($servcatresult)){
    $cattitle = $scrow["title"];
    if (in_array($cattitle, $servicesar)) {
        $scchecked = 'checked="checked"';
    } else {
        $scchecked = '';
    }

    $servcatselects .= '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$cattitle.'" value="'.$cattitle.'" '.$scchecked.'>'.$cattitle.'</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been banging my head most of the day, I tried in_array in defferent ways but never set as an empty string.. Thank you Barmar !! :)